# How to conceal Markdown syntax per-word, rather than per-paragraph?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown, conceal

I want to use Vim to write markdown in a sort-of-WYSIWYG manner (for use with an audience). For example, typing `**Bold**` should display **Bold** in bold font, with the asterisks automatically hidden as soon as I move the cursor away from the word.

I've figured out *almost* how to do this with several markdown syntax-highlighting plugins that offer concealing (vim-pandoc-syntax and plasticboy's markdown-vim-mode). The issue I'm encountering is that the markdown symbols (for example, the asterisks around the word "Bold") are visible until I start a new *paragraph* or otherwise exit the current paragraph.

Ideally I'd like the asterisks to be concealed as soon as I start a new *word* or move on from the current word.

Any ideas? I'm flexible as to which Markdown plugin I use, as long as I can achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

After some research and advice from another forum, it appears that it is not possible to have both concealable text concealaed and other concealable text *unconcealed* on the same line at the same time in vim.

I could split my paragraphs into separate lines, instead of using the Pencil plugin's soft-wrapping to have each paragraph on a single line. With each line on its own line, only one line's markdown formatting would be revealed at a time.

Another option is to `:set concealcursor=nvic`, which hides all markdown symbols entirely -- they don't show up even when the word is being edited, but the bold/italic formatting is there.

It seems that this might be my best option unless I choose a different tool entirely.